# fpdf17 import more than one page

Tags: testing

Pleaaaase help me to to fix the code. I would like to import the first and the secound page:

```
$pdf = new FPDI('P','mm','A4');

$pdf->SetTitle("test");

$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."source.pdf");
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1); 


$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, 0);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
$pdf->SetMargins(1,0,1,0);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(margin,1)

shareeditundeleteflag
```

Comment: hey, SO is not coding services.. don't copy other people code and ask people here to change to fill your need... Show us what you've done...